# Children handlers disappeared after removing and readding element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I try to switch elements between two HTML lists. In the first list, a new element must be at the end of the list. I use the jQuery `.appendTo()` method to add an element and `.remove()` to remove an element. In the second list every elements must stay in place so I use `.hide()` and `.show()`.

Here is my HTML lists :

```
List 1
<ul id="l1"></ul>
List 2
<ul id="l2"></ul>
```

An element of one of my lists looks like : `<li>Element - <span>remove</span></li>`

I add an handler to the `span` to remove the element from the list and add it in the other list.

```
let ul1 = $("ul#l1"),
    ul2 = $("ul#l2"),
    lis = ["ga", "bu", "zo", "meu"];


lis.forEach(function(e){
    let li1 = $("<li>" + e + "- </li>"),
        sp1 = $("<span>remove</span>"),
        li2 = $("<li>" + e + "- </li>"),
        sp2 = $("<span>hide</span>");

    sp1.appendTo(li1);
    li1.appendTo(ul1);

    sp2.appendTo(li2);
    li2.appendTo(ul2);
    li2.hide();

    // switching the element from the list 1 to the list 2 
    sp1.on("click", function(){
        li2.show();
        li1.remove();
    });

    // switching the element from the list 2 to the list 1 
    sp2.click(function(){
        li2.hide();
        li1.appendTo(ul1);
    });
});
```

The problem is that after re-adding the element to the first list, the handler seems to have disappeared. I add this element the same way as the first time.

Why has the `.click()` handler disappeared the second time ? Is the `.remove()` method removing children object's handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per jquery doc

https://api.jquery.com/remove/

> all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are
>   removed. To remove the elements without removing data and events, use
>   .detach() instead.

Comment: It works fine but this part of doc seems a little bit ambiguous because it doesn't explain that there is a propagation of event removing to the children.